# Mosaicking layerstacked images in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, image-mosaic

I am trying to layerstack two set of mosaicked images, or I have two sets of individual layerstacks of seperate swaths which i want to mosaic.

I am attaching the code here:

```
var roi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(68.8602, 22.6003,70.0577, 21.6079);

var collection1 = ee.ImageCollection(['COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20200205T055029_20200205T055653_T42QWK',
                                      'COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20200116T055159_20200116T060121_T42QWK',
                                      ]).select(['B8','B4','B3','B2']).filterBounds(roi);
print('Number of images in collection1:', collection1);

var stackCollection1 = function(collection1) {

  var first1 = ee.Image(collection1.first()).select([]);

  var appendBands1 = function(image, previous) {
    return ee.Image(previous).addBands(image);
  };
  return ee.Image(collection1.iterate(appendBands1, first1));
};
var stacked1 = stackCollection1(collection1).clip(roi);
print('stacked image1', stacked1);
Map.addLayer(stacked1, {min:0, max:4000}, 'stacked1');

var collection2 = ee.ImageCollection(['COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20200205T055029_20200205T055653_T42QVK',
                                      'COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20200116T055159_20200116T060121_T42QVK'
                                      ]).select(['B8','B4','B3','B2']).filterBounds(roi);
print('Number of images in collection2:', collection2);

var stackCollection2 = function(collection2) {

  var first2 = ee.Image(collection2.first()).select([]);

  var appendBands2 = function(image, previous) {
    return ee.Image(previous).addBands(image);
  };
  return ee.Image(collection2.iterate(appendBands2, first2));
};
var stacked2 = stackCollection2(collection2).clip(roi);
print('stacked image2', stacked2);
Map.addLayer(stacked2, {min:0, max:4000}, 'stacked2');
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this solve your needs?

```
// mosaic images
var mosaiced = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([stacked1, stacked2]).mosaic()
    // eventually copy properties of one image
    .set(stacked1.toDictionary(stacked1.propertyNames()));
print('mosaiced', mosaiced);
Map.addLayer(mosaiced, {min:0, max:4000}, 'mosaiced');
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much!! It's working :)